# Prove $\frac{a^2}{b^2+c^2} + \frac{b^2}{c^2+a^2} + \frac{c^2}{a^2 + b^2} \geq \frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{c+a} + \frac{c}{a+b}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R_+}$. Prove that
$$\frac{a^2}{b^2+c^2} + \frac{b^2}{c^2+a^2} + \frac{c^2}{a^2 + b^2} \geq \frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{c+a} + \frac{c}{a+b}. $$

Comment: why so more (-1) votes? Inequality seems to be interesting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\dfrac{a^2}{b^2 + c^2} - \dfrac{a}{b+c} = \dfrac{ab(a-b) + ac(a-c)}{(b+c)(b^2 + c^2)}, \\
&\dfrac{b^2}{c^2 + a^2} - \dfrac{b}{c+a} = \dfrac{bc(b-c) + ab(b-a)}{(c+a)(c^2 + a^2)}, \\
&\dfrac{c^2}{a^2 + b^2} - \dfrac{c}{a+b} = \dfrac{ac(c-a) + bc(c-b)}{(b+a)(b^2 + a^2)}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Thus we can rewrite the inequality we are to prove as:

\[ \dfrac{ab(a-b) + ac(a-c)}{(b+c)(b^2 + c^2)} + \dfrac{bc(b-c) + ab(b-a)}{(c+a)(c^2 + a^2)} + \dfrac{ac(c-a) + bc(c-b)}{(b+a)(b^2 + a^2)} \geq 0.\]

The left-hand side equals

\begin{equation}
\begin{split} &ab(a-b) \cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{(b+c)(b^2 + c^2)} - \dfrac{1}{(a+c)(c^2 + a^2)} \right) + \\
&ac(a-c) \cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{(b+c)(b^2 + c^2)} - \dfrac{1}{(b+a)(b^2 + a^2)} \right) + \\
&bc(b-c) \cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{(c+a)(c^2 + a^2)} - \dfrac{1}{(b+a)(b^2 + a^2)} \right).
\end{split} \end{equation}

Now let's take the expression in the first bracket:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\dfrac{1}{(b+c)(b^2 + c^2)} - \dfrac{1}{(a+c)(c^2 + a^2)} = \dfrac{(a+c)(c^2 + a^2) - (b+c)(b^2 + c^2)}{(b+c)(b^2 + c^2)(a+c)(c^2+a^2)}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The numerator can be expanded as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&(a+c)(c^2 + a^2) - (b+c)(b^2 + c^2) = (a-b)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ab) + c(a^2 - b^2) = \\
&(a-b)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ab + c(a+b)).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So the first term equals
\[ (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ab + bc + ca) \cdot \dfrac{ab(a-b)^2}{(b+c)(b^2 + c^2)(a+c)(c^2+a^2)}. \]

The other terms can be transformed by analogy. Finally, we obtain

\[ (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ab + bc + ca) \cdot \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{ab(a-b)^2}{(b+c)(b^2 + c^2)(a+c)(c^2+a^2)}, \]

which obviously is nonnegative for all $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R_+}$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that when you square terms like:

$\left(\frac{a}{b+c}\right)^2=\frac{a^2}{b^2+2bc+c^2}\leq \frac{a^2}{b^2+c^2}$

for $c>0$. So your ineqality is true for $c>0$.  The inequality you wrote is false for $c<0$ (take $c$ close to $-a$ for example).